# Explain this sentence to me please

Tags: meaning, negation

I'm taking this true or false questionnaire for work. One question is

> Most supervisors accept that you cannot always call in for an absence.
>
> true or false

Comment: "call-in" means "telephone the office to explain".  the correct answer is "false". (of course, you can always telephone to explain, if for some reason you can't come in)

Comment: The use of 'can' adds ambiguity. Is this the dynamic (ability to get in touch with a superior) or deontic (Is this acceptable practice?) usage?

Answer (score 2):

> ***call in*** - *Phrasal verb*
>
> 5.to telephone the place where you work and say where you are or what you are doing
>
> a. call in sick to telephone the place where you work and say you will
>   not come to work because you are sick
>
> Source: [macmillanictionary.com](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus/american/call-in_1#call-in_15)

The phrase "*Call in for absence*" is used in situations when you are unable to go to work and you call up your supervisor to inform him/her of your absence.

Your sentence therefore means- *Most supervisors accept that it is not feasible for employees to always call up and inform them of their absence*. You are asked to provide your thoughts on this sentence (true/false).